# How to await all promises in object and and return as partial record

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I was halfway asking this question when I found the solution myself so I thought I will share it briefly in case somebody looks for a similar thing.

I have an object `p` of type `Partial<Record<Index,Promise<Value>>>` so that I can reference the entries with a fixed set of keys. The keys are generated and I have to do this for a number of objects so I can't just type out all the types. I would like to await the promise so that my new return type is `Promise<Partial<Record<Index,Value>>>`

Answer (score 0):

the solution I came up with is the following:

```
function awaitEntries<T>(p: T) {
  let x: Partial<Record<keyof T, Awaited<T[keyof T]>>> = {};
  Object.entries(p).forEach(([key, p]) =>
    Promise.resolve(p).then((v) => {
      x[key as keyof T] = v;
    })
  );
  return x;
}
```